# JasperReportsPdfView: package org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I'm upgrading a spring application from 4.3.x version to 5.1.x version. When doing this I found an error for **JasperReportsPdfView**  class from the org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports package.

Also in our application we are using the jasperreports-3.6.0 jar.

### Error:

```
error: package org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports does not exist
```

### Sample Code:

```
public class PdfReportView extends JasperReportsPdfView{


    /**
     * Creating constructor
     * @param contractList
     */
    public PdfReportView(List contractList) throws JRException
    {
    }
    ;
    ;
    ;

}
```

### POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.wellpoint.ewpd</groupId>
        <artifactId>ewpd-aggregator</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../ewpd-aggregator</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>ebx-war</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ebx-war Project</name>
    <description>ebx-war Project</description>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Set to the Context Root - DO NOT REMOVE -->
                    <warName>ebx-war</warName>

                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>CrossWalks</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.class</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>

            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>                  
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.class</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <springframework.version>5.1.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>bsh</groupId>
            <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
            <version>1.2b7</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>

        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ezmorph</groupId>
            <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.28</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency> 
            <groupId>com.wellpoint.eps.ewpd.tools.xmlbeans</groupId> 
            <artifactId>Get27XBenefitAccums5010-jar</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0.2</version> 
            <classifier>sources</classifier> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.1</version>
                    <exclusions>
                           <exclusion>
                                  <groupId>org.owasp.antisamy</groupId>
                                  <artifactId>antisamy</artifactId>
                             </exclusion>
                           <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                                  <artifactId>batik-css</artifactId>
                           </exclusion>
                      <exclusion>
                           <groupId>xom</groupId>
                           <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
                      </exclusion>
                     <exclusion>
                           <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                           <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
                      </exclusion>
                     </exclusions> 

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wellpoint.ets.ebx.schemas.V4</groupId>
            <artifactId>Get27XBenefitAccumsV4</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <classifier>mystery</classifier>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
                <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
             <version>2.1.7</version>  
             <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                  <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                  <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
             <exclusion>
                  <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                  <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
             <exclusion>
                  <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                  <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.60</version>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.60</version>
            </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wellpoint.libraries.eps.epds.business</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta-poi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>            
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
          <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.0</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>          
            <classifier>jdk13</classifier>          
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wellpoint.libraries.eps.epds.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr173_1.0_api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr173_api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.keyoti</groupId>
            <artifactId>RapidSpellWeb</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>apache-xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>resolver</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-ibm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xbean_xpath</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans-qname</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.10</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
            <artifactId>xbean</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
             <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlpublic</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>xpp3_min</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4c</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.jndi</groupId>
            <artifactId>springutil</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>

        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
         -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.02</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>stax</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wellpoint.ewpd</groupId>
            <artifactId>ewpd-jar</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wellpoint</groupId>
            <artifactId>adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wellpoint.ets.ewpd</groupId>
            <artifactId>admin-method-validation</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <classifier>mystery</classifier>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ajaxanywhere</groupId>
            <artifactId>ajaxanywhere</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.6</version>
            <classifier>mystery</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <!--  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.blazesoft.oes</groupId>
            <artifactId>benefitRule</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <classifier>mystery</classifier>
        </dependency>-->
                <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wellpoint.wpd</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecidrep</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <classifier>mystery</classifier>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>myfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomahawk</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>

        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Also I can see jasperreports package in spring 4.3.24.RELEASE.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.24.RELEASE/javadoc-api/

But I'm not able to see from 5.0.0.RELEASE onwards.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/

1. Please help me to solve this issue.
2. Also please suggest some example url's to get knowledge on this.
3. Also suggest some steps that I can follow to upgrade this jar from 3.6.0 to 6.7.1 version.

Comment: Could you post your dependencies file? Like a build.gradle o something like that. It´s most likely a dependency issue

Comment: Added pom.xml, which is having spring dependencies and jasperreports dependency with version 3.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, while upgrading from the Spring lower versions to higher versions( Ex: Spring-4.x.x to Spring-5.x.x ) we need to consider the below points.

- New Features
- Supported existing features
- Removed Packages, Classes and Methods
- Dropped Support Features

From the Spring Framework github wiki and from other articles, it is confirmed that support for JasperReports has been dropped from Spring 5.x versions. So it is recommended to remove the code that are using the Japser reports from the application code or to support them by using the core-jasper reports libraries.

Reference links :

[Spring-5.x-github-wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x)

[Spring-guru-5.x-link](https://springframework.guru/what-is-new-with-spring-framework-5/)

[Dzone-Spring-5.x-features and Support](https://dzone.com/articles/whats-new-in-spring-framework-5)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your POM change this dependency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0</version>

    </dependency>
```

For this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, when changing dependencies, I always rebuild the project from my IDE (IntelliJ or Eclipse), because sometimes it doesn´t solve all the packages correctly (your problem).

You can always look for updated dependencies [here](https://mvnrepository.com/).